# Clean Python code with Sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext2, code-formatting

I would like to clean a long Python code:

- indentations (sometimes I used 2 whitespaces, sometimes 4 whitespaces), I would like to have 4 everywhre
- sometimes I have some unwanted whitespaces at the end of a line like this :
  `print "hello"       <EOL>`

Using Sublime Text's *Edit > Line > Reindent* just doesn't work for Python. Example: doing it on:

```
for i in range(27):
    if a == b:
        print a
print "finished"
```

would give

```
for i in range(27):
    if a == b:
        print a
        print "finished"
```

which is not the same thing!

**What do you use to beautify your Python code?**

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

Comment: It looks sublime expects a blank line after the if block. This is not required in PEP8

Answer (score 2):

you can use autopep8 to do this : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/

```
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive <filename>
```